# syntax error: unknown user 'munin' in statoverride file

Tags: munin, dpkg

Server running Ubuntu 12.04 lts

I installed munin the other day on a server. I decided later to remove it with apt-get.

I noticed that not everything was removed from the installation so manually removed the munin web directory and also removed the munin user-name and group from the sever.

However I have just now tried to run apt-get upgrade which is now returning an error:

dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 syntax error: unknown user 'munin' in statoverride file
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

I am now out of my depth. What does this mean? Google results have not really been helpful.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look in

```
/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

if there is any line

```
root munin 750 /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d
```

Try:

```
dpkg-statoverride --remove /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d
```

Comment: There are quite a few:  munin munin 755 /var/lib/munin
root mlocate 2755 /usr/bin/mlocate
root munin 750 /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d
munin munin 755 /var/cache/munin/www    
root ssl-cert 710 /etc/ssl/private
munin adm 750 /var/log/munin
root crontab 2755 /usr/bin/crontab   Do i just remove all the munin related ones i am guessing?

Comment: Remove only the munin related ones

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed that not everything was removed from the installation so **manually removed the munin web directory and also removed the munin user-name and group from the sever.**

**Don't do that!** Because you didn't purged properly the users stored in `/etc/passwd` file, which dpkg queries to compare with the statoverride file, do not match up and dpkg is throwing a warning. Instead purge the package and dpkg will remove all the directories and users the package created, without the user having to dirt their hands in it.

```
sudo apt-get purge package
```

This should do it.

Comment: For those Googling this, this answer is correct in that you should not manually delete package-created users/groups **in the future**. However, Alex's answer seems to work if you have made this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to reinstall apache2 cause for some reason which I could not fix, it refused to start

`$ sudo apt-get install apache2
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 syntax error:`**`unknown group 'nagios'`** `in statoverride file`

Looking into: **`dpkg/statoverride`**

`cat /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
root postdrop 2555 /usr/sbin/postdrop
root postdrop 2555 /usr/sbin/postqueue
root mlocate 2755 /usr/bin/mlocate
postfix postdrop 2710 /var/spool/postfix/public`
**`root nagios 4750 /check_icmp`**
`root ssl-cert 710 /etc/ssl/private
root crontab 2755 /usr/bin/crontab`

The solution was to:
`:/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d$ sudo sed -i '/nagios/d' /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride`

And the result
`:/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
root postdrop 2555 /usr/sbin/postdrop
root postdrop 2555 /usr/sbin/postqueue
root mlocate 2755 /usr/bin/mlocate
postfix postdrop 2710 /var/spool/postfix/public
root ssl-cert 710 /etc/ssl/private
root crontab 2755 /usr/bin/crontab`

credit: [Ubuntu unknown user in statoverride](http://rickfoosusa.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/howto-ubuntu-unknown-user-in.html)